# NodeMCU Arduino framework UDP Packet sending problem

Tags: arduino, udp, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

I've been trying to send an UDP Packet from readed ADC Value via UDP to any terminal. Unfortunately, I can't get any input on UDP terminal from the ESP directly. Here's the code:

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//////////DEFINITIONS/////////////
#define ADC A0          //macrodef for reading the adc

///////////WiFi&UDP CONFIG///////////////////
WiFiUDP UdpPilot;                                          // UDP Object for pilot
char udpSendingPacket[255] = "Hello there!";               //tab to send packet to board
unsigned int Port = 4210;                                // UDP port to send to
IPAddress destin_IP(192, 168, 0, 197);                 //IP Adress to send to
const char *softApName = "xxxxxxxx";
const char * pass = "xxxxxxxx";

/////////////////VARIABLES////////////////
int adcValueReaded = 0; //val to read from ADC
char adcToString[255];

void setup() {

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);    //Station mode on WiFiUdp
    Serial.begin(9600);     //Begin serial
    Serial.println(WiFi.begin( softApName, pass ) ? "WiFi Connection Ready!" : "WiFi Connection Failed!");
    Serial.println(UdpPilot.begin(Port)  ? "Port listening Ready!" : "Port listening Failed!");
}

void loop() {

    adcValueReaded = analogRead(ADC);

    if(adcValueReaded >= 500){
        itoa(adcValueReaded, adcToString, 10);
        UdpPilot.beginPacket(destin_IP, Port);
        UdpPilot.write(adcToString);
        UdpPilot.endPacket();
        Serial.println(adcToString);
        Serial.println(adcValueReaded);         
    }
    yield();
}
```

Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How exactly is this failing?

Comment: It's worth to mention, that I don't get any errors and I can see the values sended by serial monitor. In this case I assume, that the packet may be sent properly and passes through the UDP sending functions.